# Java program doesnt end

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(digitCount(2, 2));
    System.out.println(digitCount(22, 2));
    System.out.println(digitCount(222, 2));
    System.out.println(digitCount(232, 2));
    System.out.println(digitCount(278, 2));
    System.out.println(digitCount(0, 0));
    System.out.println(digitCount(2, 1));//the problem lies here, but dont know why
}

public static int digitCount(int number, int digit){.
    int result=0;
    if(number<0){
        return (number*-1);//this is to accomodate positive or negative numbers
    }
    if(number<10 && number==digit){
         result++;
    }else if(number%10==digit){
         result++;
         result+= digitCount(number/10,digit);
    }else{
        result+=digitCount(number/10,digit);
    }

    return result;

}
```

}

I am writing this code in order to determine how many times a digit appears in a specified number.  The code work when the digit is actually in the number, but the program runs forever when the digit is not in the number.  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Java !== Javascript

Comment: You don't stop the recursion when `number` reaches `0`, unless `digit` is `0` too. You need an `if (number == 0) return 0;`

Comment: You also have another bug.  Try `System.out.println(digitCount(-123, 2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's jump in with your parameters and find out what's going on!

You're calling your function with the parameters `number=2` and `digit=1`:

```
public static int digitCount(int number, int digit){.
    int result=0;
    if(number<0){
        return (number*-1);//this is to accomodate positive or negative numbers
    }
```

Our `number` is bigger than 0, so nothing happens so far.

```
    if(number<10 && number==digit){
         result++;
    }
```

Here `number` is smaller than 10 but it's not equal to our `digit`, so this doesn't run and we go on to the else blocks:

```
    else if(number%10==digit){
         result++;
         result+= digitCount(number/10,digit);
    }
```

For us `number%10` will be 2, which is not our `digit`, so this doesn't run either...

```
    else{
        result+=digitCount(number/10,digit);
    }
```

So this will get called instead, with `number/10` which will be 0 since it's an integer, and the function will recursively get called with (0,1) with the same problems we had just now.

What you're failing to do here is have a catch for when the number is only one digit long but it doesn't match the digit you're looking for. Just preventing the program from going to the else blocks should be enough:

```
public static int digitCount(int number, int digit){.
    int result=0;
    if(number<0){
        return (number*-1);//this is to accomodate positive or negative numbers
    }
    if(number<10){
         if(number==digit){
              result++;
         }
    }else if(number%10==digit){
         result++;
         result+= digitCount(number/10,digit);
    }else{
        result+=digitCount(number/10,digit);
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking your conditions with number 2 and digit 1:

```
public static int digitCount(int number, int digit){.
    int result=0;
    if(number<0){ // false for 2
        return (number*-1);//this is to accomodate positive or negative numbers
    }
    if(number<10 && number==digit){ // false for number 2 and digit 1
         result++;
    }else if(number%10==digit){ // false for number 2 and digit 1
         result++;
         result+= digitCount(number/10,digit);
    }else{

        // endless recursion with number 0 and digit 1
        result+=digitCount(number/10,digit); 
    }

    return result;

}
```

}

Add:

```
 public static int digitCount(int number, int digit, int result){.
    if (number==0)
        return result; // needs to be passed in due to recursion

    if(number<0){ 
    ...
```

and start as

```
    int result = digitCount(2, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a more fluent recursion function

- you don't need to store the result in a variable
- use `Math.abs` to check negative number
- return 0 when you come to 0 and if it's not the required number
- when last digit is right : return 1 + find usage in the rest
- when last digit is not : return find usage in the rest

---

```
public static int digitCount(int number, int digit) {
    number = Math.abs(number);
    if (number == 0 && digit != number) {
        return 0;
    } else if (number < 10 && number == digit) {
        return 1;
    } else if (number % 10 == digit) {
        return 1 + digitCount(number / 10, digit);
    } else {
        return digitCount(number / 10, digit);
    }
}
```